# How to add permissions to Android PhoneGap project?

Tags: android, cordova, permissions

A plugin I am using to access the AccountManager in android through phonegap requires some permissions. I am using PhoneGap 3.4.0. In the config.xml in my www folder there is a tag

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
```

I am having the hardest time figuring out how I add permissions to this config.xml file. All the other questions I've found say to alter the manifest file, but that feels wrong with me setting so many things in this config.xml file.

How do I add the permissions in the config.xml file? Comma separated list in the tag referenced above?

Here are the permissions I have added to my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check you have declared the following.

```
 <feature name="NetworkStatus">
         <param name="android-package" value="CDVConnection" />
 </feature>
```

Network status will be the feature name and value will be your class name.

In Android Manifest,

> ```
>  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
> ```

Aso check cordova_plugin.js

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
    module.exports = [{
        "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.dialogs/www/notification.js",
        "id": "org.apache.cordova.dialogs.notification",
        "merges": ["navigator.notification"]
    }, {
        "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.network-information/www/network.js",
        "id": "org.apache.cordova.network-information.network",
        "clobbers": ["navigator.connection", "navigator.network.connection"]
    }];
    module.exports.metadata = // TOP OF METADATA 
    {
        "org.apache.cordova.device": "0.2.8",
        "org.apache.cordova.network-information": "0.2.7"
    }
});
```

These are some permission types.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't anticipating having to change the android manifest at all. I guess it makes sense since the permissions are android specific.

Comment: The permissions are correct in my manifest file and I am getting `Access Denied` when trying to use the Account Manager feature still.

Comment: My phone says the app has account manager permissions, but when I use the functions I am getting an Access Denied message. I edited my question to show the permissions I'm adding.