# `navigator.notification.alert(message, null, title, 'OK');` cordova

Tags: cordova, alert

```
 native notification is not working ,
function validateForm() {
    debugger;
    if ($("#txtClaimNumber").val() == "") {
      navigator.notification.alert('Enter Value.', null, "Alert", "Close");
     // alert('Enter Value');
        return false;
    }
    if ($("#txtFirstName").val() == "") {
        alert('First Name Should be filled out in Customer Information Tab.');
        return false;
    }
    if ($("#txtLastName").val() == "") {
        alert('Last Name Should be filled out in Customer Information Tab.');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Presently I am using `alert()` in that  we can't change   the title of alert message , please help me. I followed the instructions from this

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html

```
    used  this cmd line :- $ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.core.dialogs

    I  placed 


    <plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/> in 


    app/res/xml/config.xml and also 


    <feature name="Notification">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
    </feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

undo all the changes that you have done in xml files mentioned above and

try running this command from consoleL

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

generate the build again using

```
cordova build <platform-name>
```

and see if dialogs/alerts works or not.

let me know if any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check have you declared this in cordova_plugin.js

```
{
        "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.dialogs/www/notification.js",
        "id": "org.apache.cordova.dialogs.notification",
        "merges": [
            "navigator.notification"
        ]
},
```

for more info check this.

[How to add permissions to Android PhoneGap project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090649/how-to-add-permissions-to-android-phonegap-project/24093848#24093848)